# kde is not loaded after install debian kde CD (.iso file)

Tags: linux, debian, iso-image, kde

I downloaded this .iso file:

> debian-8.2.0-i386-kde-CD-1.iso

and expected to have `KDE` desktop but CLI is loaded after installation. I also tried `startx` but just redirect to another command line.

I thought `KDE` must be installed by default with `debian-8.2.0-i386-kde-CD-1.iso`. Is it correct or not?

Comment: @BlueBerry-Vignesh4303 I tried it and the result is: command not found.

Comment: It says the latest version of xorg is installed already. @BlueBerry-Vignesh4303

Comment: does the default shortcut works **ctrl+alt+f7**?,also check this url,this might help u

Comment: ctrl+alt+f7 doesn't do anything. @BlueBerry-Vignesh4303

Comment: It might be helpful to add a link to the iso you downloaded.  I'm wondering about the filename.  This is likely to be a DVD-sized iso.  Any chance the "CD-1" portion means this is a multi-CD installation and you're loading only the first one?

Comment: This is the link: [link](http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/8.2.0/i386/iso-cd/). Yes it has multi-CD installation but in CD-1 it has KDE. @fixter1234

Comment: I read on your linked page where they describe what it **should** include, but I wonder if the maintainers messed up in building the iso files or the instructions are wrong.  KDE is not the default desktop, and it is huge.  debian-8.2.0-i386-kde-CD-1.iso, which you would expect to contain KDE, and debian-8.2.0-i386-CD-1.iso, which you would not, are exactly the same size, and I didn't spot more than a few trivial differences between them in a quick eyeball check.  My guess is that the difference in your disk is just in config files and KDE is on another disk.

Comment: If you read descriptions on that page **debian-8.2.0-i386-CD-1.iso** by default has Gnome desktop, so this is why both of them have same size. @fixter1234